# Objective-C: Programmatically Created UITableViewCell Height issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, constraint-programming

How to resize `UITableViewCell` height at runtime according to content coming from response

Here is my code:

**.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>    
@end
```

**.m**

```
import "ViewController.h"
import "CustomCellTableViewCell.h"

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self cofigureTableview];
}

-(void)cofigureTableview
{
    self.table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.table.delegate = self;
    self.table.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.table];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
      return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell = [[CustomCellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    [self setUpCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)setUpCell:(CustomCellTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (cell != nil)
     {
        UILabel *averageRatingLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        averageRatingLabel.text = @"Average Rate";
        averageRatingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        averageRatingLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        averageRatingLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        averageRatingLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        averageRatingLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        averageRatingLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:averageRatingLabel];

        /////
        UILabel *sortByLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        sortByLabel.text = @"SORT BY Value:";
        sortByLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        sortByLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        sortByLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        sortByLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        sortByLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        sortByLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:sortByLabel];


        UILabel *sortByLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        sortByLabel1.text = @"I want to adjust the row height of a UITableView according to the cell in that row. I want to adjust the row height of a UITableView according to the cell in that row.I want to adjust the row height of a UITableView according to the cell in that row";

        sortByLabel1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        sortByLabel1.numberOfLines = 0;
        sortByLabel1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        sortByLabel1.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        sortByLabel1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        sortByLabel1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:sortByLabel1];

        UILabel *sortByLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        sortByLabel2.text = @"Is there any method to achieve this:";
        sortByLabel2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        sortByLabel2.numberOfLines = 0;
        sortByLabel2.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        sortByLabel2.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        sortByLabel2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        sortByLabel2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:sortByLabel2];

        UILabel *sortByLabel3 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        sortByLabel3.text = @"This should work because tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:";
        sortByLabel3.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        sortByLabel3.numberOfLines = 0;
        sortByLabel3.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        sortByLabel3.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        sortByLabel3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        sortByLabel3.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:sortByLabel3];

        UILabel *sortByLabel4 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        sortByLabel4.text = @"then in your tableView:  in your viewDidAppearthen in your tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: update this variable like your new height and then reload the [self.yourTable reloadData] in your viewDidAppearthen in your tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: update this variable like your new height and then reload the [self.yourTable reloadData] in your viewDidAppear:";
        sortByLabel4.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        sortByLabel4.numberOfLines = 0;
        sortByLabel4.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        sortByLabel4.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        sortByLabel4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        sortByLabel4.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:sortByLabel4];


        NSDictionary *viewDict1 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(averageRatingLabel);
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[averageRatingLabel]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict1]];
       [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[averageRatingLabel]" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict1]];

        NSDictionary *viewDict2 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(sortByLabel,averageRatingLabel);
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[sortByLabel]-5-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict2]];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[averageRatingLabel]-5-[sortByLabel]" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict2]];

        NSDictionary *viewDict3 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(sortByLabel,sortByLabel1);
       [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[sortByLabel1]-5-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict3]];
       [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[sortByLabel]-5-[sortByLabel1]" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict3]];

        //
        NSDictionary *viewDict4 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(sortByLabel1,sortByLabel2);
       [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[sortByLabel2]-5-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict4]];
       [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[sortByLabel1]-5-[sortByLabel2]" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict4]];

        //
        NSDictionary *viewDict5 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(sortByLabel2,sortByLabel3);


        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[sortByLabel3]-5-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict5]];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[sortByLabel2]-5-[sortByLabel3]" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict5]];

        //
        NSDictionary *viewDict6 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(sortByLabel3,sortByLabel4);
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[sortByLabel4]-5-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict6]];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[sortByLabel3]-5-[sortByLabel4]" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict6]];

     }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    });
    [self setUpCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return [self calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:cell];

}

- (CGFloat)calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:(UITableViewCell *)sizingCell
{

    [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];
    CGSize size = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height;

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

Comment: What issue you are facing related to cell height?

Comment: I want resizable cell at runtime. My view is creating based on server response with constraints.

Comment: try one think after you add your tableview in subview just reload it and check output.

Comment: ok, I'm trying...

Comment: @SachinKhaire is your problem solve now ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to automatically adjust cell height according to content size:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 300.0f;
}
```

You can also use it like:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic height of content first you need to calculate content size then calculate height according to that height and pass that height to your table view cell height like this -

```
-(float) getHeightForText:(NSString*) text withFont:(UIFont*) font andWidth:(float) width{
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(width , 20000.0f);
    CGSize title_size;
    float totalHeight;
    SEL selector = @selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:);
    if ([text respondsToSelector:selector]) {                
        title_size = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                     attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : font }
                                        context:nil].size;
        totalHeight = ceil(title_size.height); 
    } else {                
        title_size = [text sizeWithFont:font
                      constrainedToSize:constraint
                          lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];                
        totalHeight = title_size.height ;                
    }
    CGFloat height = MAX(totalHeight, 40.0f);
    return height;            
}
```

Pass this **height** to table view cell -

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return height;
}
```

Comment: Hi, @neha, your logic is working but sometimes my label getting space from Top if I close my last label to super view else getting bottom space when I release it.

Comment: Like ,    @" V:[sortByLabel3]-5-[sortByLabel4] "  OR  
@" V:[sortByLabel3]-5-[sortByLabel4]-5-|"

Comment: @Sachin , You can use these lines in your cellForRowAtIndex method -
for (UIView *subview in [self.contentView subviews]) 
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) 
    {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

If my answer is working please accept this .

Answer (score 0):

[image]

My view like this, but I don't known it's priority as one-by-one, one-after-one or May be UIButton first or last. Nothing fixed it's creating based on response of server.

Answer (score -1):

Use Code below to adjust cell height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
switch(indexPath.row){
   case:0
    return 100;
   break;

   case:1
    return 200;
   break;
    }
 }
```

According to the case resize your cell height.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yep, But I don't know how many contents coming from response. It's may be UIButtons or UILabels etc. All these are setting using constraints while checking the last view.

I want resizable cell at runtime.

Comment: thanks, but my fields may be 50 or more my view is not fixed it's changeable based on response.

Comment: This answer is correct. There is no other place that you should specify the tableview row height, except this delegate. If you want it to be changeable, then you need to store an array of cell heights and return them here. when you receive data, you recalculate the heights and update the heightArray, and call [tableView reloadData]; and your cells will be updated accordingly.